# CSS only tabs using input:checked

Tags: html, css, tabs

I found [this example](http://csscience.com/css3-tabs/#tabB) (the "checked" version) and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/2cTwA/

But I want to wrap the input and labels inside a container element (like `nav`), and if I do that the tabs stop working :(

Is there any solution for this?

found solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2cTwA/7/

Comment: I found a solution!! I can wrap the labels inside an elmenet, and just leave the inputs inside the same parent as the tabs. They are hidden anyway so I dont care:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slight HTML and CSS modification - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cTwA/11/)

***CSS***

```css
input { display: none; }

nav { overflow: hidden }
label   { float: left; display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px; }
label a { color: #d33; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }   

.tab { display: none; border: 1px solid #333; padding: 10px; }
a[name="tab1"] + .tab { display: block }
:target + .tab { display: block }
:target ~ a[name="tab1"] + .tab { display: none  }
```

***HTML***

```
<section class="tab-area tabs-checked">

    <nav>
        <input checked type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-A" />
        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-B" />
        <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab-C" />

        <label class="tab-link" for="tab-A"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></label>
        <label class="tab-link" for="tab-B"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></label>
        <label class="tab-link" for="tab-C"><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></label>
    </nav>

    <a name="tab3"></a>
    <article class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 3</h3>          
    </article>

    <a name="tab2"></a>
    <article class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    </article>    

    <a name="tab1"></a>
    <article class="tab">
        <h3>Tab 1.</h3>
    </article>

</section>
```

Comment: hmm there's no active tab by default

Comment: @Alex now it has an active tab.. just a small caveat - to use the `~` sibling selector properly you have to revert the order of your article tabs

Answer (score 1):

You're using the sibling selector (~), and by using a containing element such as nav, you are removing the inputs and labels from being siblings of the articles.

You simply need to rewrite your css where you use the tilde.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sass example for 12(max) tabs using CSS only

```
.tabs {

  input[type=radio] {
    display: none;

    @for $i from 1 through 12 {

      &:nth-of-type(#{$i}):checked ~ .content .tab:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }

  label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .tab {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and here is the html markup

```
  <div class="tabs">
    <input name="controls" type="radio" id="controls-tab" checked="true"/>
    <label for="controls-tab">controls</label>
    <input name="controls" type="radio" id="panels-tab"/>
    <label for="panels-tab">panels</label>
    <input name="controls" type="radio" id="readme-tab"/>
    <label for="readme-tab">readme</label>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="tab">
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

no need to relatively position tab divs inside content div. no need to set content height.